# VueJS :: How to subscribe to a reactive object without a component?

Tags: vuejs3

I want to play around with a `reactive()` object with as little as possible additional cruft. Is it possible to subscribe to reactive object in plain JS? Something like `subscribe` in the following:

```js
const x: any = {
  a: [],
  b: 2,
  c: { q: 0 }
}
const y: any = reactive(x); 

// subscribe does not exist AFAIK - that's the question ...
subscribe(y, (...args: any[]) => { console.log('Something reactive happened', args); });

y.a = [1,2,3];
```

Comment: [watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) and [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) are two of the most common general ways of responding (or updating something) when some reactive state changes.  For your case of just wanting to console log something anytime `y` changes, I would use a watcher

Comment: Oh yep, `watch` is the answer I was looking for - confirmed it works outside of Component context too. I didn't know about it because I've learnt Vue3 via the options API and am just now getting around to learning the composition API. Thanks! If you can be bothered writing it up I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: No problem! I've written it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) and [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) are two of the most common ways of responding (or updating something) when some reactive state changes. For your case of just wanting to `console.log` something anytime `y` changes, I would use a watcher:

```js
watch(y, (newY) => {
  console.log('Something reactive happened', newY)
})
```